# Pthread not printing correct value

Tags: c, multithreading

Here's a simple program I wrote. It creates 10 threads in a for loop and each thread prints the value of i:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void* basic_function(void *num){
    int cur_num = *(int*)num;
    printf("Current thread number is :%d\n", cur_num);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    pthread_t thread_id [10];
    void * exit_status[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, basic_function, &i); 
        printf("i is: %d\n", i);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        pthread_join(thread_id[i], &exit_status[i]);


    return 0;
}
```

I think the output should look something like some print statements from 0 to 9, in the correct order:

```
Current thread number is: 0
i is: 0
Current thread number is: 1
i is: 1
Current thread number is: 2
i is: 2
...
```

But instead, my output is:

```
i is: 0
i is: 1
i is: 2
i is: 3
i is: 4
i is: 5
Current thread number is: 6
Current thread number is: 6
i is: 6
Current thread number is: 6
Current thread number is: 6
Current thread number is: 6
Current thread number is: 6
Current thread number is: 6
i is: 7
Current thread number is: 7
i is: 8
Current thread number is: 9
Current thread number is: 9
i is: 9
```

Why is thread 6 created multiple times? Why are some threads not created? And also, why I always get different output when I run the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the argument that is passed to the thread function points to the same variable - `i`.

And as the variable `i` is constantly updated from the `main` function, the threads always get the latest value at the time of their running and the threads do that in parallel with the `main` method. Additionally, it may happen that the threads access the variable once the loop is already finished and in such case it's undefined behaviour.

The solution is either to allocate a copy of `i` on the heap and pass the pointer to the copy. Or another a bit dirtier solution is to cast the `i` to pointer, pass as the argument and then in the thread convert back to int. This relies on int being smaller than pointer though, which is quite common but on some obscure architecture may not be true (probably not the case for such small numbers).

Comment: I understand your first solution. But I don't know why cast `i` to a pointer can solve the problem. I think it has the same effect as        `pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, basic_function, &i)`, which is what I did in my post.

Comment: No it does not have the same effect because casting to a pointer creates a a copy of the integer, which is carried by the pointer. Not portable as Zbynek pointed out, but reliable if it works